Larvel Carbon::now() returns wrong time / timezone
I would like to get the current time for the timezone "Europe/Berlin" using
Carbon::now()

in my Laravel 10 Application.
Now my problem: Let's say we have 4 o'clock, but Carbon::now() returns 2 o'clock. Setting the time zone using
Carbon::now()->setTimezone('Europe/Berlin');

or
Carbon::now('Europe/Berlin');

does not change anything. Changing the time zone in config/app.php didn't help either.
What does work, however, is PHP's built-in "date()" function. However, I would like to stay with carbon.
And here comes the crazy thing, if I print the value of now() using only "echo()", the time is correct. So the value using echo and return ist different.
The time on the server/computer is also configured correctly.
Can someone explain the error to me or tell me what I'm doing wrong or missing?
Note: I've already tried to clear the configuration cache using php artisan config:clear

What is the timezone in your app.php?

What do you get if you do var_dump(Carbon::now());?  Also try var_dump(new DateTime());

@vixducis the same as in the code above: "Europe/Berlin"

@aynber var_dump returns the associated object. The "date" property also contains the correct time in both objects.

If Carbon::now() is correct, and echo Carbon::now() is correct, then it should be correct. How are you using it that you're getting a time 2 hours off (which looks to be UTC)

I'm developing a rest api and for testing purposes I returned Carbon::now() in this case the time is two hours behind. Also i want to compare the value with another date.

What was the exact value that Carbon::now() returned? I've noticed that sometimes when I return a timestamp via ajax, it returns the UTC value, such as 2014-10-29T15:06:19.000000Z, when the stored timestamp is 2014-10-29 11:06:19 New York time

Ah ha, found the explanation, back in the Laravel 7 upgrade guide. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade#date-serialization -- The guide mentions how to change it on the model, but using the ->format() on now() will do the same thing

For my timezone it returns "2024-04-03T13:11:32.903890Z" when its actually 15:11 not 13:11. I'm calling the api via postman, so its no async request.

Using "format()" it shows the correct time. Thank you. However, I still wonder why the return value is different than the output one. Unfortunately I can't compare times with a string :)

Sorry, by async, I kind of meant anything that returns a JSON response (ajax? it's still early). 13:11 is the UTC timezone, which you can tell with the lone Z at the end. Otherwise, it would have the offset +02:00 (or something like that) at the end
